# Mysql - caching results using temp. tables / php scripting (memcached?)

Tags: php, mysql

I have main table with milions of rows, the operations performed on it looks like that:

get random single random row **=>** return to php script **=>** delete it, repeat on failure (mysql_affected_rows) - that's it.

Meant operations are performed on-demand, e.g. one script gets ONE row at a time when it's necessary, but usually there are several instances of different scripts doing that very fast. **one php function handles the "requests"**

It's quite fast (optimised quite well), but I'm looking for something faster.
What I wanted to do was a creation of new table, getting like 1k rows from main table once in a while, putting them to the "cache" one and then perform the operations on the "cache" table similar way I was doing it one the main one.

Will there be any performance gained?
Should I use MEMORY (HEAP) engine or MyISAM engine?

---

**if there is some way to not to use the DB and do the "temporary table" part purely within php and *nix OS, that would be even better**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building a caching system from scratch you could check out some existing ones:

- [Memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/)
- [APC](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php)
- [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/)
- [Zend Cache](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Platform/zend_cache_api.htm)
- [eAccelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAccelerator)